# .Rmarkdown leaves a lot of empty space between the chunk and the plot

Tags: plot, r-markdown, chunks

I am including several plots in a .Rmarkdown document, but the plots are leaving a lot of space between the chunk and the plot itself. Any idea why this might happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Please supply an reproducible example. What output are you producing? Pdf?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer HTML

Comment: The default sets no space between the chunk and the plot. The space you see might be the `margin` of the plotting device. Try `par(mar = c(4, 4, 0.5, 0.5))`. If that does not solve your problem we need a reproducible example.

Comment: I have got a feeling that you have to include `fig.pos = 'h'` in either the chunk option or in the global chunk options. This should **hold** the position of the figure based on where you have put it in your document.